# Ubuntu One Account not working

Tags: ubuntu-one

Yesterday I wanted to try out the Ubuntu One storage feature and logged in. I couldn't sync anything from either Windows or Ubuntu.

In Windows nothing really happens.
In Ubuntu I get a `File Sync error. (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED))` error.

If I log onto the website it gives me a "Something has gone wrong" error. If I go to my account page it says I'm not subscribed to the file storage and if I click on the sign up button it goes to the "Something has gone...." page.

I tried deleting every device via the homepage. Changing my password didn't work.

My girlfriend created an account and it works perfectly on her machine and mine.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you [contacted](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) Ubuntu One about your account? It sounds like there's a problem with their software recognizing your account.

Comment: Hi, thanks didn't see there was a contact page, I only looked under the "Help" section and saw askubuntu. I have contacted them and waiting for a response.

Comment: Sounds good. Be sure to update your post here if you get an answer.

Comment: Haven't got a reply but it works now, but I think someone has fixed it. This guy also had the exact same issues https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/663049 .

Comment: You can answer your own question with the details of the bug and mark it as the correct answer so that others with the same problem will find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to access the cloud after emailing them. Didn't get any confirmation email from them but got a 'Welcome to Ubuntu One' email, and it has worked ever since.

Answer (score 2):

There is a current service disruption for some users.

[Ubuntu One Service Status](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Files)

Comment: Well after mailing them I got a 'Welcome to Ubuntu One' email and it started working after this.